# ¿Cómo llenar un select html creado durante la ejecución de la aplicación web con un string desde JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Tengo unos selects (dropdown) que se crean en una tabla a través de una función, el problema es que sólo se está llenando el primer select, los demás me salen vacíos, les estoy asignando el id="combo" a cada select creado, pero cuando se trata de llenarse, sólo uno se carga con los datos y los demás aparecen vacíos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
switch (opcion) {
                        case opcion = 1:
                            renglon.append('<td style="width:10%; vertical-align: middle;"><div class="divNumero"><label></label></div><img style="width: 25px;" src="images/Data-Erase.png" class="imgMinus" title= "Eliminar" /></td>'
                                + '<td colspan="2" style="text-align: justify; width: 60%;"><textarea cols="20" rows="2" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; height: 60px; resize: none; font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">' + pregunta + '</textarea></td>'
                                + '<td style="width:10%;"><label style="font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">Sí/No</label></td>'
                                + '<td style="width:20%;"><label style="font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">' + opciones + '</label></td>'
                                + '<td><label style="font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">' + respuesta + '</label></td>'
                                + '<td><input class="valor" type ="number" min="1" style="width: 40px;" /></td>'
                                + '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkN" /></td>'
                                + '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkN" /></td>'//Nueva Opción 
                                + '<td><select name="combo" id="combo"></select ></td>' //Usuarios
                                + '<td><input type="datetime-local" id="dates" min="' + fecMin + '" max="' + fecMax + '" value="' + today + '"></td>');//Date
                            /*min="2018-01-02"*/
                            debugger

                                  var str = "oscar,karla,lalo,lino,Eder";
                    var str2 = "1,2,8,4,5";
                    str = str.split(',');
                    str2 = str2.split(',');

                    $.each(str, function (idx, val) {
                        $('#combo').append("<option value='" + str2[idx] + "'> " + val + " </option>");
                    });                       

                            var td = $('<td style="width:20%;"></td>');
                            td.append(prioridad);
                            renglon.append(td);
                            $("#visualizacionPreg").append(renglon);
                            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos errores en tu consulta:

El primero es que los ID de los elementos html son únicos, por lo cual es incorrecto asignarle el mismo ID a todos.

El segundo es que estas cargando los "selects" por id, lo cual esta bien que solo cargue el primero. Lo que debes hacer es lo mismo pero asignarle a los selects una misma clase css como por ejemplo `select-load` y luego haces

```
$.each(str, function (idx, val) {
    $('.select-load').append("<option value='" + str2[idx] + "'> " + val + " </option>");
});
```

De esta manera vas a cargar todos los selects!

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo a tu consulta como para que entiendas lo que digo

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s747mLtL/2/)

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, algo nuevo aprendí, no sabía eso de que podía afectar todos los 'select' con tener la misma css, me funcionó perfecto.